# Show multiple qr-code on single webpage in PHP

Tags: php, qr-code

I am using PHP qrcode plugin to generate qr-code. It is working fine if I generate single but problem is when I try to generate multiple qr-code on single webpage then it is showing only one qr-code.

I am directly displaying qr-code on webpage, I am not creating PNG/SVG file.

Here is the code show far.

```
include('qrlib.php'); 
include('config.php'); 

$codeContents = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a'; 

    // generating 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, QR_ECLEVEL_L); 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, QR_ECLEVEL_M); 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, QR_ECLEVEL_Q); 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, QR_ECLEVEL_H);
```

**Note:** I have downloaded the plugin from http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you need to change the code contents between generating new images surely?

Comment: i did that but it is still showing single qr-code.